# Recordset Paging isn't Working

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, recordset

Can anyone tell me why my recordset paging isn't working. I don't know a whole lot about this stuff, the parts of it I have in my code I pulled from this Microsoft website link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125

Here is my code:

```
Dim con, con2, rec, rec2, dsn, dsn2, sql, sql2, rName, sDate, eDate, intPageCount
rName=Request.Form("rn")
sDate=FormatDateTime(Request.Form("sD"), 2)
eDate=FormatDateTime(Request.Form("eD"), 2)

dsn = "Radio"
dsn2 = "InfoLib_SQL"
sql = "SELECT * FROM T_RadioControlLog WHERE RadioName = '"&rName&"' AND CONVERT(date, Date, 101) >= 
       CONVERT(date, '"&sDate&"', 101) AND CONVERT(date, Date, 101) <= CONVERT(date, '"&eDate&"', 101)"

set con=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rec=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rec.CursorLocation=3

con.Open dsn, "pw", "pw"
rec.Open sql, con
rec.PageSize=5
intPageCount=rec.PageCount

Select Case Request("Action")
    case "<<"
        intpage =1
    case"<"
        intpage = Request("intpage")-1
        if intpage < 1 then intpage = 1
    case ">"
        intpage = Request("intpage")+1
        if intpage > intPageCount then intpage = intPageCount
    case ">>"
        intpage = intPageCount
    case else
        intpage = 1
end select

If NOT rec.eof Then
Response.write("<table>")
rec.AbsolutePage = intpage
For intRecord = 1 to rec.PageSize
    Response.write("<tr><td>Radio Name</td><td>Date</td><td>Employee Name</td><td>ID#</td></tr>")   
    Response.write("<tr><td>" & rec.fields("RadioName") & "</td>")  
    Response.Write("<td>" & rec.fields("Date") & "</td>")
    set con2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    set rec2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sql2 = "SELECT EMP_NA FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE ID='"&rec.fields("ID#")&"'"
    con2.Open dsn2, "pw", "pw"
    rec2.Open sql2, con2
    Response.Write("<td>" & rec2.fields("EMP") & "</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>" & rec.fields("ID#")& "</td></tr>")
    rec.movenext
    rec2.close
    con2.close
    set rec2=nothing
    set con2=nothing
If rec.EOF Then Exit For
Next
%>
<tr>
<form name="pageNav" action="results.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="intpage" value="<%=intpage%>">
<input type="submit" name="Action" value="<<">
<input type="submit" name="Action" value="<">
<input type="submit" name="Action" value=">">
<input type="submit" name="Action" value=">>">
Page: <%=intpage & " of " & intPageCount%>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<%
Else
Response.write("Sorry, no entries were found.")
End If


rec.close
set rec=nothing
con.close
set con=nothing
```

The calls to the DB work and entries are definetly returned, I get a small table with 5 entries as my recordset is set to return but when I click the `>>, <, >, etc.` it doesn't display anything, the page just goes blank. If someone can explain how recordset paging works that would be great.

Comment: if you view the source of the blank page (ie right-click and choose "View Source" from context menu) is there any HTML? Error messages?

Comment: I don't really know where to begin if I'm honest. It's a while since I've seen code like this... No offence but that sample you've taken from the M$ site is horrendous. Better resources exist like [4guysfromrolla.com - Paging through Database Results N Records at a Time](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121298-1.shtml), that article also links to another article that shows paging via SQL Server cutting out the client cursor altogether.

Comment: Also this article on [CodeProject.com - ADO Recordset Paging in ASP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619/ADO-Recordset-Paging-in-ASP) is another good example with step by step instructions. Two seconds in Google Search.

Comment: @Lankymart I am aware of those websites and have them bookmarked already. Thank you for posting them anyway. I went through the trouble of asking a question and posting my code on here in the hopes I'd have a more personalized response. My google searches take the same amount of time as yours, we must both have great ISPs :D

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional I didn't see any errors

Comment: @JimmyGoodson You want personalised? ok. The approach is terrible. You say you know about those articles?, then I have to ask...why did you ignore them? The 4guysfromrolla approach is sound and the follow on article about SQL Server paging is where you should be aiming. Without having a breakdown of your requirement its very hard to give useful advice except stop and start again. I apologise if this seems harsh but I am (believe it or not), trying to help you.

Comment: @Lankymart I realize you're trying to help, which is why I responded to your snarkiness comedically. I did thank you for your post incase you skipped that part... I didn't ignore them, and as a matter of fact I tried to use the 4guys solution but it just doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me and it didn't work. I'm going to get back to beating my head against the keyboard now lol

Comment: I'd like to combine the Microsoft link with the 4guys link by adding to the 'Case' clause a resonse.redirect(href='thisfile.asp?curpage=" & curpage - 1") or something along the lines of that. Does anyone know if something like this would work or what syntax I should follow in order to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comments on your method.

You `Dim` `intPageCount` but not `intPage` not a big deal but still a personal preference that you should `Dim` it.

You have fields from previous pages that you don't seem to save during postback. Specifically I see this section of code

```
rName=Request.Form("rn")
sDate=FormatDateTime(Request.Form("sD"), 2)
eDate=FormatDateTime(Request.Form("eD"), 2)
```

but no corresponding section like this

```
<form name="pageNav" action="results.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="rn" value="<%=rName%>">
<input type="hidden" name="sD" value="<%=sDate%>">
<input type="hidden" name="eD" value="<%=eDate%>">
<input type="hidden" name="intpage" value="<%=intpage%>">
```

to enable callback for those values on postback.

Comment: I could have Dim intpage but it seemed to work without it but you're right I could. Is that the correct syntax for using a asp vbscript variable as an HTML element value? As far as the "pageNav" form goes, that form is only used for navigation. I'm not sure why I would set my values being passed from my search function into a hidden input type... What do you mean exactly by callback for those values on postback? Are you saying I'm losing the values I pass when the page posts again by clicking on the nav buttons ( >,>>,<< )?

Comment: @JimmyGoodson answering each item: 1)Yes it is the correct syntax. 2)The values go into the form so you will have them again when you click on your paging buttons. 3)Request.Form("rn") calls a field from the previous page which will now be results.asp when you click a nav button. So Request.Form("rn") is doing a "callback" on the action="result.asp" "postback". 4)Yes you are losing the values when you click the nav buttons.

Comment: OMG man, ty so much lol... I was not thinking clearly, I did what you said and it worked flawlessly. I wasn't seeing the big picture on this, ty for reminding me how this stuff flows haha

Answer (score -9):

```
Function ShowFolderList(folderspec)

   Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)

   Set fc = f.Files

   For Each f1 in fc

      s = s & f1.name 

      s = s & "<BR>"

   Next

   ShowFolderList = s

End Function
```

This is from Help. There are no wildcards in FSO. You have to do it yourself. So test if `f1.name` meets your requirements then copy that file.